# How to resolve warning: multi-character character constant in Linux C++

Tags: c++

```
#ifdef WIN32
#   define TARGET_OS 'W_NT'
```

I am getting C++ warning in Linux multi-character character constant. at the below line. How to resolve this warning.

```
#if TARGET_OS == 'W_CE'
```

Comment: You don't "resolve" the warning. You understand what it means and decide whether your program is correct. (This will depend on the way `TARGET_OS` is used.)

Answer (score 3):

String constants use double quotes, single quotes are for character constants.

To suppress the warning if this is what you mean you can use `-Wno-multichar` gcc option.

Comment: I believe OP *does* mean a character constant, `'W_CE'`, which is equivalent to 0x575f4345 in some endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define preprocessor constants as strings or chars when testing them in `#if`. Perhaps coding

```
#if TARGET_OS_IS_WIN_NT
   /* do something for Windows NT */
#endif

#if TARGET_OS_IS_LINUX
   /* do something for Linux */
#endif
```

Better yet, consider using multi-system libraries like e.g. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) -they did all the boring job of handling system specific things and provide you with a nice common API.

Comment: I tried like this now . but still errors are coming                 #if (TARGET_OS_W_NT || TARGET_OS_W_CE)

Comment: do we need to define in .h file or .cpp file what TARGET_OS_W_NT means or can we directly use that ?

Comment: @Sudhakar you would do  #if defined(TARGET_OS_W_NT) || defined(TARGET_OS_W_CE) and simply pass a single preprocessor define in your target configuration as to what the target is (-DTARGET_OS_LINUX)